# Timer and TimerTask not update

Tags: java, timer

I have an app that could set the time for processing. The problems is when I update the time, the processing will increase. For example:
Initially the timer start at 07:00AM
Let say, I update the timer to 08:00AM then the next day onwards, the program will run again at 07:00AM and also at 08:00AM. (The 07:00AM is still in scheduler, how to remove the 07:00AM?)
How to make the scheduler to only run the 08:00AM the next day?

```
public void setKonfigurasi(String name, String value) {
    log.info(SERVLET_NAME + "Entering setKonfigurasi");
    amBean.setParam(name,value); //update the time into database
    //name = 'processFileConf|kodPT|userA|20140312 08:30 AM'
    // reschedule timer after configured by user
    try {
        String kodPT = name.substring(name.indexOf("|") + 1, name.indexOf("|",name.indexOf("|") + 1)); 
        String configStr = value.substring(2); //get the new time
        String currentStr = CommonUtil.getCurrentDate();
        DateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy KK:mm:ss a");
        Date currentDate=new Date() ;
        Date configDate = dateformat.parse(currentStr+" "+configStr);
        long config = configDate.getTime();
        long current = currentDate.getTime();

        // today
        long delay = config-current;
        if (delay < 0)
            // tomorrow
            delay += (1000*60*60*24);

        // create the timer and timer task objects
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() { 
            public void run() { 
                System.out.println("showtime for "+kodPT);
                processFile("auto"+kodPT);
            } 
        }, delay, 1000*60*60*24);

        ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent = EtServletContextListener.getContext();
        ServletContext servletContext = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
        servletContext.removeAttribute ("timer");
        servletContext.setAttribute ("timer", timer);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception on date format : "+e.getMessage());
    }            
    log.info(SERVLET_NAME + "Exiting setKonfigurasi");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `cancel()` on the previous timer and create a new one. The javadoc says:

> Terminates this timer, discarding any currently scheduled tasks. Does
>   not interfere with a currently executing task (if it exists). Once a
>   timer has been terminated, its execution thread terminates gracefully,
>   and no more tasks may be scheduled on it.

Comment: do I call cancel() before timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()? In case I have set schedule for more then 1, then how about the other?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out about how to do what I want. Instead of using java.util.Timer to create the timer, we should use javax.ejb.Timer since the Timer in ejb have an info to identified each timer.
[Timer Service EJB](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365551/EJB-21-The-Timer-Service)